# PayPal API QueryParameters not found

Tags: c#, paypal, server

[image: Screenshot]

I copied and pasted a section from **[here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#list-payment-resources)** (You will have to scroll to the top - click C# on the right and scroll down/refresh) and have installed the PayPal API into the project `Install-Package PayPal` but `QueryParameters` is not found - is there a second part or something I should already know about?

---

Code from site

```
OAuthTokenCredential tokenCredential =new OAuthTokenCredential("<CLIENT_ID>", "<CLIENT_SECRET>");

string accessToken = tokenCredential.GetAccessToken();
var parameters = new QueryParameters();
parameters.SetCount("10");

PaymentHistory paymentHistory = Payment.Get(accessToken, parameters);
```

Comment: Try to right click on `QueryParameters` and see if there is an tip such as `Add some example reference` (**for example:** `Add System. Collections`) Also, if you're using VS15 you have to click on the yellow lightbulb first. This **might** solve your problem.

Comment: @cramopy There's no `resolve` available (what I used for the others) and I'm using VS13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAICS are the PayPal `QueryParameters` part of `PayPal.Util`. Please try if you can access this namespace.

If not you can add it manually (as a class) using [this link](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/blob/master/Source/SDK/Util/QueryParameters.cs).

You should also consider downloading the whole SDK if the above does not work using [nuget](http://"https://www.nuget.org/packages/PayPal).

Comment: I've added `using PayPal.Util;` and the error remains.

Comment: Please try all 3 solutions, as I'm not similar to the PayPal API. Also the link you provided does not even cobtain the code you "provided" with a screenshot in any type. I could help you some more if you update/correct it properly!

Comment: With the link you need to scroll to the top and click C#, it's cURL by default. I have the class and I have the whole project.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the language tabs on the [PayPal REST API Reference](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/) page have sample code that is woefully out-of-date (and in this case, completely incorrect since `Payment.Get(...)` is intended to return a single `payment` resource, not a list).  The PayPal docs team is well aware of this issue and will be removing the language tabs in the near future in favor of the SDKs providing their own samples via GitHub.

I'd recommend checking out the [PayPal .NET SDK samples project](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/tree/develop/Samples) on GitHub, which does a much better job of showing you not only the code, but displaying the request/response details for each API operation.

Regarding getting the payment history, you'll want to do the following using the PayPal .NET SDK:

```cs
using PayPal.Api;

// Authenticate with PayPal and setup the APIContext object.
var config = ConfigManager.Instance.GetProperties();
var accessToken = new OAuthTokenCredential(config).GetAccessToken();
var apiContext = new APIContext(accessToken)
{
    Config = config
};

// Get the payment history
var paymentHistory = Payment.List(apiContext, count: 10, startIndex: 5);
```